# How to make background move slower than text in Skrollr?

Tags: javascript, skrollr

tIt seems that I did as it is in example [here](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/bg_constant_speed_more.html) but my background moving faster than text. What did I do wrong?

My HTML:

```
<div id="loader-bg" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100000="background-position:0px -50000px;"></div>
<div id="skrollr-body">
    Content text...
</div>
```

Comment: You need to share your code, since the page you linked works. Did you notice it's using `background-attachment:fixed`?

Comment: Thank you very much! That thing I didn't noticed =)

Comment: I added it as an answer which you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demo uses `background-attachment:fixed` to get full control of the movement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to set the class attribute on your loader-bg div

```
class="skrollable skrollable-between"
```

Comment: No, skrollr adds them automatically